# Deleted user on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

Why do I sometimes see a user card under a question or answer which looks like the following?

> [image]

Has the user been deleted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

That's a profile that was deleted a long time ago. Back then the names weren't anonymised like they are now.

Now you'd see

> user123456

(or whatever their id was)

Comment: Where can i find a discussion about that ? 
i mean a new rules/feature that talk about this kind of rules

Comment: @gagantous - here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88836/generic-ize-a-users-name-when-their-account-is-destroyed

Comment: by curiosity, does the name appear the same way if the question get migrated to a site the op isnt member of ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 No. You will just get the normal username which is not hyperlinked.